# Querying Customers who have rented a movie at least once every week or in the Weekend

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a DB for movie_rental. The Tables I have are for :

1. Customer Level:

   - Primary key: Customer_id(INT)
   - first_name(VARCHAR)
   - last_name(VARCHAR)
2. Movie Level:

   - Primary key: Film_id(INT)
   - title(VARCHAR)
   - category(VARCHAR)
3. Rental Level:

   - Primary key: Rental_id(INT).

   The other columns in this table are:

   - Rental_date(DATETIME)
   - customer_id(INT)
   - film_id(INT)
   - payment_date(DATETIME)
   - amount(DECIMAL(5,2))

Now the question is to Create a master list of customers categorized by the following:

- Regulars, who rent at least once a week
- Weekenders, for whom most of their rentals come on Saturday and Sundays

I am not looking for the code here but the logic to approach this problem. Have tried quite a number of ways but was not able to form the logic as to how I can look up for a customer id in each week. The code I tried is as follows:

```
select
   r.customer_id
 , concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as Customer_Name
 , dayname(r.rental_date) as day_of_rental
 , case
     when dayname(r.rental_date) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
     then 'Regulars'
     else 'Weekenders'
   end as Customer_Category
from rental r
inner join customer c on r.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

I know it is not correct but I am not able to think beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the current approach is that every rental of every customer will be treated separately. I am assuming a customer might rent more than once and so, we will need to aggregate all rental data for a customer to calculate the category.

So to create the master table, you have mentioned in the logic that weekenders are customers "for whom most of their rentals come on Saturday and Sundays", whereas regulars are customers who rent at least once a week.

2 questions:-

1. What is the logic for "most" for weekenders?
2. Are these two categories mutually exclusive? From the statement it does not seem so, because a customer might rent only on a Saturday or a Sunday.

I have tried a solution in Oracle SQL dialect (working but performance can be improved) with the logic being thus: If the customer has rented more on weekdays than on weekends, the customer is a Regular, else a Weekender. This query can be modified based on the answers to the above questions.

```
select
        c.customer_id,
         c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name as Customer_Name,
            case
        when r.reg_count>r.we_count then 'Regulars'
            else 'Weekenders'
        end as Customer_Category
from customer c
inner join
(select customer_id, count(case when trim(to_char(rental_date, 'DAY')) in ('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY') then 1 end) as reg_count, 
        count(case when trim(to_char(rental_date, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') then 1 end) as we_count
        from rental group by customer_id) r on r.customer_id=c.customer_id;
```

Updated query based on clarity given in comment:-

```
select
        c.customer_id,
        c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name as Customer_Name,
        case when rg.cnt>0 then 1 else 0 end as REGULAR,
        case when we.cnt>0 then 1 else 0 end as WEEKENDER
from customer c
left outer join
(select customer_id, count(rental_id) cnt from rental where trim(to_char(rental_date, 'DAY')) in ('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY') group by customer_id) rg on rg.customer_id=c.customer_id
left outer join
(select customer_id, count(rental_id) cnt from rental where trim(to_char(rental_date, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') group by customer_id) we on we.customer_id=c.customer_id;
```

Test Data :

```
insert into customer values (1, 'nonsensical', 'coder');
insert into rental values(1, 1, sysdate, 1, sysdate, 500);

insert into customer values (2, 'foo', 'bar');
insert into rental values(2, 2, sysdate-5, 2, sysdate-5, 800); [Current day is Friday]
```

Query Output (first query):

```
CUSTOMER_ID    CUSTOMER_NAME          CUSTOMER_CATEGORY
1              nonsensical coder      Regulars
2              foo bar                Weekenders
```

Query Output (second query):

```
CUSTOMER_ID   CUSTOMER_NAME       REGULAR   WEEKENDER
1             nonsensical coder    0         1
2             foo bar              1         0
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @ashutosh. To answer your question:

1. 'Most' here most probably means Either Saturday or Sunday or both
2. These two categories are not mutually exclusive. People from regulars can spill over to weekenders

My problem here is to check how do I check each customer id in every week to confirm them under regulars. Same for weekenders, have to check if each customer id appears in all the weekends

Comment: Have provided the updated query and output

Comment: Since the categories are not mutually exclusive, we can keep them both related to one customer

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the `customer` table for this.  You can add that in after you have the classification.

To solve the problem, you need the following information:

- The total number of rentals.
- The total number of weeks with a rental.
- The total number of weeks overall or with no rental.
- The total number of rentals on weekend days.

You can obtain this information using aggregation:

```
select r.customer_id,
       count(*) as num_rentals,
       count(distinct yearweek(rental_date)) as num_weeks,
       (to_days(max(rental_date)) - to_days(min(rental_date)) ) / 7 as num_weeks_overall,
       sum(dayname(r.rental_date) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')) as weekend_rentals
from rental r
group by r.customer_id;
```

Now, your question is a bit vague on thresholds and what to do if someone only rents on weekends but does so every week.  So, I'll just make arbitrary assumptions for the final categorization:

```
select r.customer_id,
       (case when num_weeks > 10 and
                  num_weeks >= num_weeks_overall * 0.9
             then 'Regular'     -- at least 10 weeks and rents in 90% of the weeks
             when weekend_rentals >= 0.8 * num_rentals
             then 'Weekender'   -- 80% of rentals are on the weekend'
             else 'Hoi Polloi'
         end) as category
from (select r.customer_id,
             count(*) as num_rentals,
             count(distinct yearweek(rental_date)) as num_weeks,
             (to_days(max(rental_date)) - to_days(min(rental_date)) ) / 7 as num_weeks_overall,
             sum(dayname(r.rental_date) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')) as weekend_rentals
      from rental r
      group by r.customer_id
     ) r;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. I am just wondering here if this code checks if each customer id has transacted at least once each week to qualify as a Regular?

Comment: @nonsensical_coder . . . The rules it uses are specified in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a study of cohorts. First find the minimal expression of each group:

```
# Weekday regulars
SELECT
   customer_id
FROM rental
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) < 5 # 0-4 are weekdays

# Weekend warriors
SELECT
   customer_id
FROM rental
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) > 4 # 5 and 6 are weekends
```

Now we know how to get a listing of customers who have rented on weekdays and weekends, inclusive. These queries only actually tell us that these were customers who visited on a day in the given series, hence we need to make some judgements.

Let's introduce a periodicity, which then allows us to gain thresholds. We'll need aggregation too, so we're going to count the weeks that are distinctly knowable by grouping to the `rental.customer_id`.

```
# Weekday regulars
SELECT
   customer_id
 , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
FROM rental
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) < 5
GROUP BY customer_id

# Weekend warriors
SELECT
   customer_id
 , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
FROM rental
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) > 4 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

We also need a determinant period:

```
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), '2019-01-01') / 7) AS weeks_in_period
```

Put those together:

```
# Weekday regulars
SELECT
   customer_id
 , period.total_weeks
 , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
FROM rental
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) < 5
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), '2019-01-01') / 7) AS total_weeks
) AS period
GROUP BY customer_id

# Weekend warriors
SELECT
   customer_id
 , period.total_weeks
 , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
FROM rental
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), '2019-01-01') / 7) AS total_weeks
) AS period
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) > 4 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

So now we can introduce our threshold accumulator per cohort.

```
# Weekday regulars
SELECT
   customer_id
 , period.total_weeks
 , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
FROM rental
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) < 5
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), '2019-01-01') / 7) AS total_weeks
) AS period
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING total_weeks = weeks_as_customer

# Weekend warriors
SELECT
   customer_id
 , period.total_weeks
 , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
FROM rental
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), '2019-01-01') / 7) AS total_weeks
) AS period
WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`) > 4 
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING total_weeks = weeks_as_customer
```

Then we can use these to subquery our master list.

```
SELECT
   customer.customer_id
 , CONCAT(customer.first_name, ' ', customer.last_name) as customer_name
 , CASE
     WHEN regulars.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'regular'
     WHEN weekenders.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'weekender'
     ELSE NULL
   AS category
FROM customer
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), '2019-01-01') / 7) AS total_weeks
) AS period
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
     rental.customer_id
   , period.total_weeks
   , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(rental.`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
  FROM rental
  WHERE WEEKDAY(rental.`date`) < 5
  GROUP BY rental.customer_id
  HAVING total_weeks = weeks_as_customer
) AS regulars ON customer.customer_id = regulars.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
     rental.customer_id
   , period.total_weeks
   , COUNT(DISTINCT YEARWEEK(rental.`date`)) AS weeks_as_customer
  FROM rental
  WHERE WEEKDAY(rental.`date`) > 4
  GROUP BY rental.customer_id
  HAVING total_weeks = weeks_as_customer
) AS weekenders ON customer.customer_id = weekenders.customer_id
HAVING category IS NOT NULL
```

There is some ambiguity as far as whether cross-cohorts are to be left out (regulars who missed a week because they rented on the weekend-only at least once, for instance). You would need to work this type of inclusivity/exclusivity question out.

This would involve going back to the cohort-specific queries to introduce and tune the queries to explain that degree of further comprehension, and/or add other cohort cross-cutting subqueries that can be combined in other ways to establish better and/or more comprehensions at the top view.

However, I think what I've provided matches reasonably with what you've provided given this caveat.

Comment: Thanks @jared!! Let me try this and see